# Constitution Class in TNG era?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, spaceship

Are there any [Constitution](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Constitution_class) class starships (refit or otherwise) still in active service during the time of The Next Generation, Deep Space Nine or Voyager series? I can not remember any appearing on screen in any of the shows, which seems odd since the ship was fairly versatile and strong on the front line.

There are at least three other classes of ship commissioned around the same time frame as the Constitution (or at least around the time of the refit), which we do still see in service in the 24<sup>th</sup> century ([Excelsior](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Excelsior_class), [Miranda](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Miranda_class) and [Oberth](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Oberth_class)); so there is no reason that the Constitution class couldn't have been kept up to date and in service as well.

Comment: Yes, Yes, excellent Q. The Excelsior was *slightly* newer than the refit, ... but Miranda was the same generation, and Oberth was a lowly science vessel vs. the Constitution as a heavy cruiser... so if those two survived, then the Constitution refit **certainly** should've.

Comment: The USS Bozeman (Soyuz-Class) was almost certainly in active service after the events of "Cause and Effect", at least until it reached the nearest starbase...

Comment: How many 80-year-old US Navy ships are on active duty?

Comment: @KeithThompson Watching the large scale battle scenes in Deep Space Nine, there are a lot of 80 year old vessels still in active duty. Alternatively, there are a lot of vessels using an 80 year old hull design at least.

Comment: @Xantec: There are US Navy ships on DS9? Apart from the Constitution (commissioned 1797, now a museum) and the Pueblo (commissioned 1968, captured by North Korea), the oldest active-duty US Navy ship is the USS Denver, commissioned in 1968, 46 years ago. My point is that, based on current US Navy practice, it's entirely plausible that all Constitution class ships would be out of service by the TNG era. Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_current_ships_of_the_United_States_Navy

Comment: @KeithThompson Ha, no, there are no US Navy ships in DSN (sounds like a setup for a Macross/Star Trek cross over). But there are Miranda and Excelsior class ships shown in DSN, which is the Star Trek equivalent to an 80 year old US Naval vessel still being in active service today.

Comment: I would think there are a number of constitution-class Starships still and use by the Federation. but I have no idea what their names or ID numbers would be

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While the decision was taken by the writers of TNG and subsequent series not to have any Constitution-class ships in the TV show, there were a couple of cheeky references that managed to slip through.

In TNG "[Best of Both Worlds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Best_of_Both_Worlds_%28Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation%29)", you can clearly see (on the left of the image) the hull of a Constitution-class vessel in the wreckage at Wolf 359. The implication is that this ship was either in service or (more likely) pulled out of mothballs for the futile defence of Earth.

Although the shots show two different hull sections, behind-the-scenes [sources](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Unnamed_Constitution_class_starships) indicate the model used for *both* shots was that of the self-destructed Enterprise made for Star Trek III: The Search for Spock.

[image]

---

There was an exchange in TNG : [The Battle](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Battle_%28episode%29) where we see that the USS Stargazer was originally intended to be a **Constitution**-class vessel. Due to budgetary reasons, it was  then redesignated (for the show) as a *Constellation*-Class vessel.

**[Original Script](http://www.st-minutiae.com/academy/literature329/110.txt):**

> Turbolift opens TO BRING Picard onto the bridge, unnoticed by most as
>   Tasha silences the ALERT and Wesley turns to Riker.
>
> **WESLEY :** *It's an old style starship, **Constitution Class**, heading this
>   way under impulse power, sir.*

Episode [Transcript](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/110.htm):

> **WESLEY:** *It's an old style starship, **Constellation Class**, heading this way under impulse power, sir.*

---

Outside of the TV show, you can clearly see a second Constitution-class vessel fighting alongside the first one on the cover of the Doctor Who/Trek crossover "[Assimilation²](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Assimilation%C2%B2,_Issue_7)".

[image]

---

There is also a suggestion that the [USS Republic](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/USS_Republic_%28NCC-1371%29) (seen in TOS: Court Martial) is still in service as a training vessel in the TNG era. Although not seen in-canon, it's referenced in the video game "Star Trek: 25th Anniversary" as well as "Klingon Academy" and "Star Fleet Battles".

Comment: "There is also a suggestion that the USS Republic (seen in TOS: Court Martial) is still in service as a training vessel in the TNG era." - where is that suggestion made, and what does it look like? The three videos you list all appear to play in the 23rd century.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - Technically it was in simulation in Klingon Academy, but still

Answer (score 13):

There are canonically (as far as my research leads me to believe) NO Constitution-class starships in service in the TNG era.

All of the surviving original Constitution-class ships were refitted around 2270 in order to prolong their lives until the 2290s as the [following quote](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Constitution_class) indicates:

> In the late 2260s to early 2270s, the Constitution-class starships
>   underwent their final major refit program. The actual refitting took
>   eighteen months of work and essentially a new vessel was built onto
>   the bones of the old, replacing virtually every major system. Thus,
>   the Constitution-class continued in service for a further twenty
>   years.
>
> [...]
>
> Major changes were made to the interior of the Constitution-class
>   starships; many new systems were added and existing ones upgraded.
>   Summarizing, only the internal structure of the saucer and very little
>   of the engineering hull and neck may have survived the 2270s refit.
>   (Star Trek: The Motion Picture)
>
> Some refit configurations had the warp nacelles rotated 90 degrees and
>   included additional hatches along both sides of the saucer. (TNG:
>   "Booby Trap")

Other TOS-movie era starship types that have survived until TNG were all designed specifically in the 2260s and 70s using the Constitution refit technology which is obviously more robust and future-proof than the original Constitution designs. Miranda-class, Obert-class and Excelsior-class have all thrived through to the TNG era because they could cope with the upgrades and modifications needed through the 70 or so years of service and proved to be versatile designs. It could be postulated that the first dedicated, long-service starships, the Constitution-class, were the prototypes for human deep-space exploration and were not designed to be futureproof. 2260s and 70s designs may have been designed specifically for longevity and for ease of upgrade.

HOWEVER:

That all said, there is ONE example of a Constitution-class ship that was in service up to the battle of Wolf 359, because the wreckage of one is visible in the scene where the Enterprise D arrives at the battle site:
[image: Constitution engineering hull]

The saucer of one is apparently visible too, just before the ad break following the same scene:

[image: Constitution saucer]

The Ex Astris Scientia website identifies the model used for this scene as the destroyed Enterprise model from Star Trek III, and this has been inferred [from information provided by the production staff](http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/articles/wolf359.htm) but never confirmed as canon.

The screenshots are the only evidence of the existence of a Constitution class ship being at Wolf 359 and the only canon evidence of a Constitution-class in the TNG era.

So the final answer I would give is that there was a total of one Constitution class ship in service until 2366, where it was destroyed at Wolf 359. I myself prefer to take the opinion that there were none, and that the existence of Constitution parts in the Wolf 359 debris was simply a production decision that has never been made canon - the Ex Astris Scientia page I linked to above contains a lot of text that indicates the production staff wanted to deny the existence of the Constitution class stuff in the wreckage.

Comment: Memory Alpha quotes (without a canon source to back them up) are considered fan-fiction.

Comment: @Richard Which quote are you saying has no canon backup?

Comment: @Xantec - "Thus, the Constitution-class continued in service for a further twenty years." for example. Purest speculation since no retirement date was ever laid down for the Constitution-class

Comment: @Richard Yea, that bit is speculative.

Comment: @Xantec - The perils of quoting wiki is that anyone can add anything.

Comment: @Richard True, but one of the advantages of wiki is that anyone can correct it if they spot an error.

Comment: One could argue that anything that isn't on the screen is not canonical. I recognise that M-A is essentially a "fan-fiction" site, but in past answers (both from myself and from others) it is takes as being as close to canon as possible for the majority of the questions asked here and on other sites. Canonically, the Enterprise was scheduled for decommissioning in Star Trek III, which was 15 years after the events of the Motion Picture. The Ent-A, which was stated to have been another Constitution-refit (not a new ship) lasted through another 5-year mission up until the events of ST6.

Comment: Another possibility is that there were no *Constitution*-class ships "in service" in 2367, but a museum ship was pressed into duty for that exceptional situation. Just more speculation!

Comment: "The Ex Astris Scientia website identifies the model used for this scene as the destroyed Enterprise model from Star Trek III, and this has been inferred from information provided by the production staff but never confirmed as canon." - I presume here you mean that it's not "confirmed as canon" that those were the debris of a Consitution class ship, not that this was supposed to be the debris of the original original Enterprise in-universe (that would have to somehow have made it from around the Genesis planet to Wolf 359).

Answer (score 2):

There aren't any listed in any of the typical sources as still existing in that time frame.  That being said, in the TNG episode Best of Both Worlds pt. 2, among the wreckage the Enterprise D finds in the aftermath of the [Battle at Wolf 359](http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/articles/wolf359.htm), there are several screen captures that show debris that appears to come from a Constitution class vessel.  It appears likely that models from the movies were re-used to add to the debris field.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've never quite known if books count as canon or not, but I'm currently reading Star Trek TNG:The children of Hamlin, in which the USS Ferrell which has two of the main book characters on board, and is destroyed, is described as a Constitution Class ship. Like I say, I'm not sure how canon this is, though.

Answer (score -4):

No, because the writers of Star Trek said that the limbs were too vulnerable, like where the neck of the ship and the arms holding the nacelles. That's why the Excelsior class was made with a more compact design. The two other classes were being slowly pushed out of service and they weren't interested for battle; their design was also not as open either. So that's why.

Comment: Could you make this more clear?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Exchange! This looks like it *could* be a good answer, if it had better citations. Please could you add a source for your statement that "the writers of Star Trek said ..."?